# How to set an image visibility after animation is complete

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to set an image visibility after an animation ends, but i'm have difficulty.

I have created few images and set the tag for each. Whenever the user clicks the image the visibility gets set to invisible. I have also created a method that animates the images. I would like when the animation finishes for the visibility of the images to reset to Visible. Apologies,if this sounds a bit unclear i'm not entirely sure how to word this question. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  public void popBubbles(View view) {


    final String tag = String.valueOf(view.getTag());

    if(tag=="0"){
        bubble.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }else if(tag=="1"){
        bubble1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }else if(tag=="2"){
        bubble2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


    }else if(tag=="3"){
        bubble3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }else if(tag=="4"){
        bubble4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }else if(tag=="5"){
        bubble5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }else if(tag=="6"){
        bubble6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }else if(tag=="7"){
        bubble7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }else  if(tag=="8"){
        bubble8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
 }

 public void animateBubbles() {

    for (final ImageView img : IMGS) {


        animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img, "translationY", 0f, -deviceHeight);
        animation.setDuration(4000);
        animation.start();
        animation.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is in kotlin but you can add a listener to the animation use the on AnimationEnd() method like this.

```
animation.addListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {

        }
    })
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

set Animation listener and override methods. You can write your logic in **onAnimationEnd** method

```
    animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    //Do operation on ImageView
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });
```